# Python - Converting String Numbers To Float

Tags: python, list, numbers, int

I want to convert string numbers on a list to float numbers
and i can't do it, so i need some help.

```
num = '0.00003533'

print('{:f}'.format(float(num)))
```

formatting it without decimals, only returns a float of 0.000035, i need the entire string in a float.

```
print('{:8f}'.format(float(num)))
```

adding the exact decimal works, but the numbers in the list with decimals varies greatly, so i can't manually add it everytime, how could i automatically add the correct decimal number inside the format?
something like '{':exactdecimalf'}  exactdecinal being a variable.

i'm using a module that requires float, which is why i can't print it directly from the string format.

Comment: please be clear add one example of your input and output that you want

Comment: Why not just `print(float(num))` just `float(num)` alone I believe does what you’re asking..

Comment: Keep it as a string if you want to print it the way it was, and convert it to a float only for numerical operations. But be aware of [floating point gotchas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: Are the items in your list strings or numbers?

Comment: strings but i got it answered. thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this

```
from decimal import Decimal
num = '0.00003533'
print(Decimal(num)) #0.00003533
```

if you want to print as string

```
print ('{:f}'.format(Decimal(num)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe double precision will suit you.

```
from decimal import Decimal
print ('{:f}'.format(Decimal(num)))
```

Answer (score -1):

You can split the string and take the length of the last part with

```
len(num.split(".")[1])
```

Then use that as the number of decimals.